# Два разных фреймворка используют одну аннотацию

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Например `Dagger 2` и `Spring` или `Guice` используют аннотацию `@Inject`.  Есть способы как то решить грамотно этот вопрос и использовать оба таких фреймворка?

Comment: Если пакеты у аннотаций разные то просто пишите весь путь к аннотации

Comment: мм, благодарю. Просто не работал особо с аннотациями и тем более не сталкивался с тем, чтобы два фреймворка с одинаковыми аннотациями в одном проекте использовались